Create event listener for map tables in SQLAlchemy
I have two models in my application.
class Building(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "buildings"

    address_id = mapped_column(BigInteger, ForeignKey("addresses.id"), nullable=False)
    name = mapped_column(String(6), nullable=True, default=None)

    address = relationship("Address", foreign_keys=[address_id], lazy="raise")
    contacts = relationship("Contact", secondary=BuildingContacts, lazy="raise")

and
class Contact(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "contacts"

    type = mapped_column(Enum(ContactTypes, name="contact_types"), nullable=False)
    value = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)

My BaseModel looks like:
engine: AsyncEngine = create_async_engine(
    app_settings.db.database_url,
    echo=app_settings.debug,
    echo_pool=app_settings.debug,
    pool_size=app_settings.db.pool_size,
    max_overflow=0,
    pool_pre_ping=True,
)
async_session: async_sessionmaker[AsyncSession] = async_sessionmaker(
    engine,
    class_=AsyncSession,
    expire_on_commit=False,
)
database = databases.Database(app_settings.db.database_url)


async def get_session() -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, AsyncSession]:
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class BaseModel(Base):
    __abstract__ = True

    id = mapped_column(sa.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    uuid = mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=False), default=lambda: str(uuid4()), unique=True, nullable=False)

    created_at = mapped_column(sa.DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=sa.sql.func.now())
    updated_at = mapped_column(sa.DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=sa.sql.func.now(), onupdate=sa.sql.func.now())

There's nothing special, but I also have map table to connect Building and Contacts(many-2-many) and it looks like:
BuildingContacts = Table(
    "building_contacts",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("building_id", BigInteger, ForeignKey("buildings.id"), nullable=False),
    Column("contact_id", BigInteger, ForeignKey("contacts.id"), nullable=False),
)

My problem is: I can't create event listeners for BuildingContacts in classical way:
@event.listens_for(BuildingContacts, "after_insert")
def after_insert_listener(mapper, connection, target):
    print(f"Inserted new record in BuildingContacts: {target}")

it's not working with any others Identifiers with Error 'AttributeError: after_insert'.
Could someone explain, how can I listen these map tables?
I tried to use any other Identifiers, but I'm always catching AttributeError

It seems this event probably isn't fired for tables but only for mapped classes.

Maybe you can try to watch an event, like "after_update" on Contact and check if the relationship changed.  It appears to track changes to relationships but I'm not sure how much information is available from the event.
Or promote the secondary table to a full blown Orm Class and track events on that:  association-object

